# why does "ctrl+a+d" exit ssh session?

Tags: ssh

I use ssh to connect to a remomte linux machine. I opened two virtual screens using command `screen`. Then I notice from `screen -ls` that I'm attached to one screen. Thus I input `ctrl+a+d` in order to exit the screen. However, I find myself exit the ssh session instead of the screen session, why? and how to deal with it?

Answer (score 7):

Because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> logs you out of your current session. The <kbd>A</kbd> has nothing to do with it.

You're supposed to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> to exit your `screen` session.

Comment: These are two separate keystrokes, don't hold `Ctrl` while pressing `D`.